# Error on OnBlur after using useReduce in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure it out, why am I getting the error 'TypeError: can't access property "trim", action.val is undefined' after I tried to set the PassDispach on ValidateEmailHandler (which is used to trigger the unblur of the pass input) ? It seems to work on validateEmailHandler. I have tried setting the initial value of PassDefaultState to a string and this also throws me an error

```
const emailReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "USER_INPUT") {
    return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.includes("@") };
  }
  if (action.type === "INPUT_BLUR") {
    return { value: state.value, isValid: state.value.includes("@") };
  }
  return { value: "", isValid: false };
};

const passReducer = (state, action) => {
  if ((action.type = "PASS_INPUT")) {
    return {
      ...state,
      value: action.val,
      isValid: action.val.trim().length > 6, 
    };
  }
  if ((action.type = "PASS_BLUR")) {
//this is where the error happens
    return {
      ...state,
    };
  }
  return { value: "", isValid: false };
};

const PassDefaultState = {
  value: "",
  isValid: null,
};

const MailDefaultState = {
  value: "",
  isValid: null,
};

const Login = (props) => {
  // ! Email STATE ----------------------
  const [emailState, dispatchEmail] = useReducer(emailReducer, MailDefaultState);

  // ! PASSWORD STATE ----------------------
  const [passState, passDispach] = useReducer(passReducer, PassDefaultState);

  const { isValid: passIsValid } = passState;
  const { isValid: mailIsValid } = emailState;

  useEffect(() => {
    const identifier = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Checking form validity!");
      setFormIsValid(mailIsValid && passIsValid);
    }, 500);

    return () => {
      console.log("CLEANUP");
      clearTimeout(identifier);
    };
  }, [passIsValid, mailIsValid]);

  const emailChangeHandler = (event) => {
    dispatchEmail({ type: "USER_INPUT", val: event.target.value });
  };

  const passwordChangeHandler = (event) => {
    passDispach({ type: "PASS_INPUT", val: event.target.value });

    setFormIsValid(emailState.isValid && passState.isValid);
  };

  const validateEmailHandler = () => {
    dispatchEmail({ type: "INPUT_BLUR" });
  };

  const validatePasswordhandler = () => {
    passDispach({ type: "PASS_BLUR" });
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onLogin(emailState.value, passState.value);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.login}>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            emailState.isValid === false ? classes.invalid : ""
          }`}
        >
          <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            value={emailState.value}
            onChange={emailChangeHandler}
            onBlur={validateEmailHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            passState.isValid === false ? classes.invalid : ""
          }`}
        >
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            value={passState.value}
            onChange={passwordChangeHandler}
            onBlur={validatePasswordhandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <Button type="submit" className={classes.btn} disabled={!formIsValid}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: your error is not on that line, it's on the previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 if ((action.type = "PASS_INPUT")) {
```

Here you need to use === instead of =, the code you wrote is trying to assign a "PASS_INPUT" to action.type while you should chec the value